# Python Animated plotting, one point at a time

Tags: python, animation, plot, scatter

I have a set of points [index, minimum] and I would like to scatter one point i (index[i],minimum[i]) at a time so that I can see the evolution of the plot. 
I would like to know how I can do that. I have tried a time- delay like:

```
    plt.figure()
    for i in range (np.size(index)):
        plt.plot(index[i], minimum[i],'*')
        plt.show()    
        time.sleep(1)
```

it did not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `It did not work` means ? Can you post the complete error ?

Comment: There is no error. It did not work means, the plotting process won't be shown in steps. I get the final plot seen only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might seem stupid but did you import the time library ? Also there is no indentation, is your code really like that or that's a copy/paste fail ?

Edit: Answer in comments, use plt.pause(1), see http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause

Comment: Yes I did. The indention is as a matter of fact a copy paste fail yes. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with plt.pause(1) ?
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause

Comment: Thank you. It works as I want it to with plt.pause(1).

Answer (score 0):

you should use an "animate" plot :

http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html

and here some good example :

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You do have to use a nan arrays to plot empty values then update your array as you move in time. Here is a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

nbPoints = 100

nanArray = np.array(np.ones(nbPoints))
nanArray[:] = np.nan

index = range(nbPoints)
minimum = np.random.randint(5, size=nbPoints)
minimumPlotData = nanArray 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0, nbPoints)
ax.set_ylim(min(minimum), max(minimum))
li, = ax.plot(index,minimumPlotData, marker = 'o', linestyle="")

fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show(block=False)
for i in range(nbPoints):
    minimumPlotData[i]=minimum[i]
    li.set_ydata(minimumPlotData)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
```